# Swift inheritance and Segmentation fault 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have run into a problem where xcode (both 7 and 8, swift version both 2 and 3) gives segmentation fault when building, and I have been able to reproduce it with a minimal amount of code. Before submitting a bug to Apple I would like to ask the community if I am doing something really stupid first :-) Never mind that the following code doesn't do anything useful; I have removed everything else to isolate the core of the problem.

The first base class is aware of a subclass. This is nothing more strange than that a Person is aware of its Parent and that a Parent is also a Person.

And this works fine, until I override init in the class Area. (And again, although it does nothing here, there is a reason to override it, of course. But that code is not part of the problem and therefore removed from this example.)

With Swift 2 I could add an empty extension for Navigatable, and then it would build and run just fine. With Swift 3 I am not so lucky. The compiler crashes while resolving type for 'Venue?'.

Any thoughts?

```
var _a: Area? = nil

class Content {
    init(venue: Venue?) { }
}

class Navigatable : Content {
    override init(venue: Venue?) {
        super.init(venue: venue)
    }
}

class Area : Navigatable {
    // This wicked thing causes the problem. Without it compiles fine:
    override init(venue: Venue?) {
        super.init(venue: venue)
    }
}

class Venue : Area {
    override init(venue: Venue?) {
        super.init(venue: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could see the `segmentation fault` with the code which you have defined the classes in order and `_a` declaration. If you move your `_a` declaration after your `Area` class definition, then everything works fine. I could see in the logs that the compiler is failing to determine the `type` of `_a` without its definition at the beginning. `swift::TypeChecker:` Good catch though!

Comment: you should report it http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: And also you have mentioned that without `override init` in your `Area` class works fine because as said above, the type checker is checking for `Area` type and then in override it checks for `Venue` which is child of `Area` again. This confuses the compiler. Might be this is the cause, not sure.

Comment: Interesting that moving the `_a` declaration made a difference. In the real case, the declaration is a member of another class in another file, so it is not so easily worked around as moving the declaration to the bottom.

Comment: FYI - while this is a bug in the compiler, it's also code you should never write. A base class should never know about any of its subclasses. That's just poor object oriented design.